# Value-Error and not a value error when calling pd.merge

Tags: pandas

Consider the following code:

```
df_strcol = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["82809","27809"], "y": [1,-1]})
df_intcol = pd.DataFrame({"x": [82809,27809], "z": [10,-10]})
pd.merge(df_strcol,df_intcol, on="x")
```

When I call pd.merge, I get a

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns.

Fine, the df_strcol has type object and this does not allow to be merged with int.
Now consider this slight change:

```
df_objcol = pd.DataFrame({"x": [82809,27809], "v": [100,-100]})
df_objcol["x"] = df_objcol["x"].astype(np.object_)
```

I again have a df of type object - I enforced it. Now calling pd.merge

```
pd.merge(df_objcol,df_intcol, on="x")
```

does not give a ValueError. What is wrong here?

Comment: Yes, I understand why it can work - but the error message is just wrong: "You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns." This message would apply in both cases